# What are the semantics of VM_UFFD_MISSING?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, page-fault

I'm reading through the Linux kernel's page fault handler (`linux-4.14.198`), and noticed the following block of code:

```
        /* Deliver the page fault to userland, check inside PT lock */
        if (userfaultfd_missing(vma)) {
            pte_unmap_unlock(vmf->pte, vmf->ptl);
            return handle_userfault(vmf, VM_UFFD_MISSING);
        }
```

The definition of `userfaultfd_missing` is that `vm_flags` includes `VM_UFFD_MISSING`. However, the only comment on this flag is the cryptic `missing pages tracking` comment on the macro definition.

**What does this flag mean, and what exactly is "userfault" handling?**

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html

Comment: These days, kernel can either handle page faults itself, as in the days of old, or engage an user space helper. Very useful for VMs it seems.